# unknown column when column is found in on table

Tags: mysql

I am running into the unknown clause error and can not figure it out. I am a little green to SQL but not totally green. Here is my code.

```
SELECT tg.name, tg.current_amount, tg.priority, tgc.needed, tgh.date
FROM  tb_goal tg, tb_goal_college tgc, tb_goal_home tgh 
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT tgc.needed, tgc.id, tgc.goal_id 
    FROM tb_goal_college tgc, tb_goal tg
) AS T ON tg.id = T.id
```

I get the error that Unknown column tg,=.id in 'on clause'.

The column exists in tg and I do not see the problem.

Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
SELECT tg.name, tg.current_amount, tg.priority, tgc.needed, tgh.date
FROM   tb_goal_college tgc, tb_goal_home tgh ,tb_goal tg
CROSS JOIN (
   SELECT tgc.needed, tgc.id, tgc.goal_id 
   FROM tb_goal_college tgc, tb_goal a
   ) AS T ON tg.id = T.id
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked but I do not really see why that worked and mine did not.